# Sitecore 6.6 and RenderPartial

Tags: sitecore, renderpartial

It doesn't seem like Sitecore likes the use of Html.RenderPartial. If I try to render a partial view instead of using a Sitecore Placeholder I get and error:

c:\Sitecore\milwaukeetool\Website\Views\Products\Index.cshtml(13): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Has anyone had success doing a RenderPartial in Sitecore 6.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to fully qualify the path of the partial view in the RenderPartial method as Sitecore seems to search /Views/Sitecore if not fully qualified.